# How to read a spark saved file in java code

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I have a file TrainDataSpark.java in which I am processing some data and at end of it I am saving my spark processed data to a directory called Predictions with below code

```
predictions.saveAsTextFile("Predictions");
```

In same TrainDataSpark.java i am adding below code part just after above line.

```
OutputGeneratorOptimized ouputGenerator = new OutputGeneratorOptimized();
final Path predictionFilePath = Paths.get("/Predictions/part-00000");
final Path outputHtml = Paths.get("/outputHtml.html");
ouputGenerator.getFormattedHtml(input,predictionFilePath,outputHtml);
```

And I am getting NoSuchFile exception for /Predictions/part-00000 . I have tried all possible paths but it fails. I think the java code searches for the File on my local system and not hdfs cluster. Is there a way to get file path from cluster so I can pass it furthur? OR is there a way to load my Predictions file to local instead of cluster  so as the java part runs with out error?

Comment: What is the result for `Paths.get("/Predictions)` ?

Comment: It is just the path /user/username/Predictions/part-00000

Comment: Does the file physically exist under `/Predictions/part-00000` after calling `saveAsTextFile`?

Comment: Yes.. After calling  predictions.saveAsTextFile("Predictions");  the Predictions folder gets created on hdfs. inside which is part-00000. I want to read this file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this way...

```
String predictionFilePath ="hdfs://pathToHDFS/user/username/Predictions/part-00000";
String outputHtml = "hdfs://pathToHDFS/user/username/outputHtml.html";

URI uriRead = URI.create(predictionFilePath);
URI uriOut = URI.create(outputHtml);

Configuration conf = new Configuration ();

FileSystem fileRead = FileSystem.get (uriRead, conf);
FileSystem fileWrite = FileSystem.get (uriOut, conf);

FSDataInputStream in = fileRead.open(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(uriRead));
FSDataOutputStream out = fileWrite.append(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(uriOut));

/*Java code that uses stream objects to write and read*/
OutputGeneratorOptimized ouputGenerator = new OutputGeneratorOptimized();
ouputGenerator.getFormattedHtml(input,in,out);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are running Spark on a cluster. `Paths.get` looks for the file in the local file system on every node separately, while it exists on hdfs. You  can probably load the file using `sc.textFile("hdfs:/Predictions")` (or `sc.textFile("Predictions")`).

If, on the other hand, you'd like to save the local file system, you'r gonna need to `collect` the RDD first and save it using regular Java IO.